# Smarty add two 0 after ",'

Tags: php, smarty

I have my variable

```
{assign var='reduc' value=$valueprice}
{assign var='prix' value='30,00'}
```

I did that

```
{$prix - ($prix * $reduc)}
```

But i want the result to be displayed with two number after the "," at the end always ! like if the result is :

```
30 => 30,00 
24,5 => 24,50
```

I already tried with |string_format:"%.2f" it is not working

Comment: You don't say what "not working" means and I know nothing about Smarty but `'30,00'` does not look as a number that a computer can understand. Do you mean `30.00` by chance?

Answer (score 0):

Using float variables for money values is not good, see for example http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/

So if you are using integer values instead you could do something like:

```
{$dollar},{$cent|string_format:"%02d"}
```